# Golang, GAE, redirect user?

Tags: html, google-app-engine, redirect, go

How can I redirect a page request in Go running on GAE, so that the user's address would display correctly without resorting to displaying a redirection page? For example, if user would type:

```
www.hello.com/1
```

I'd want my Go application to redirect the user to:

```
www.hello.com/one
```

Without resorting to:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "<HEAD><meta HTTP-EQUIV=\"REFRESH\" content=\"0; url=/one\"></HEAD>")
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For a one-off:

```
func oneHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  http.Redirect(w, r, "/one", http.StatusMovedPermanently)
}
```

If this happens a few times, you can create a redirect handler instead:

```
func redirectHandler(path string) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) { 
  return func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.Redirect(w, r, path, http.StatusMovedPermanently)
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
func init() {
  http.HandleFunc("/one", oneHandler)
  http.HandleFunc("/1", redirectHandler("/one"))
  http.HandleFunc("/two", twoHandler)
  http.HandleFunc("/2", redirectHandler("/two"))
  //etc.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
func handler(rw http.ResponseWriter, ...) {
    rw.SetHeader("Status", "302")
    rw.SetHeader("Location", "/one")
}
```

Comment: For those using Go1, `SetHeader` is deprecated. Use `w.Header().Set("Status","302")` instead.